# how to increase the top border distance? ( ul li )

Tags: css

I have an "ul" list and I want a border-top on the "li", but I don't want the default distance between the top border and the text, I need more distance.

Unfortunately I don't see a way to make this work, border-spacing should work but it doesn't, just afect around..

```
border-spacing: 10px;
```

```css
#links {
 font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #98af85;
 margin-left:-38px;
 padding-top:4px;
}
#links ul{
 list-style: none; 
}
#links ul li {
 padding: 0px 47px 0px 0px;
 white-space:nowrap;
 display: inline-table;
 border-spacing: 10px;
}
#links ul li a {
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #98af85;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#links ul li a:hover {
 color: #3b8686;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-decoration: none;
 border-top: 9px solid #b8dc7c;
}
```

```html
<div id="links">
    
 <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>    
</ul>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simple use `padding-top`:

```css
#links {
    font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #98af85;
    margin-left:-38px;
    padding-top:4px;
}
#links ul {
    list-style: none;
}
#links ul li {
    padding: 0px 47px 0px 0px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    display: inline-table;
    border-spacing: 10px;
}
#links ul li a {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #98af85;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#links ul li a:hover {
    color: #3b8686;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-top: 9px solid #b8dc7c;
    padding-top: 10px;/*Add padding-top*/
}
```

```html
<div id="links">
    
 <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>    
</ul>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Yes good call ! I think i tried margin-top instead, thats why didn't work. Thank you mate :)